# How to pass object as ajax get argument?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, get

I have the following ajax call:

```
.ajax({
       url: 'uploadExternalImage',  //Server script to process data
       type: 'GET',
       success: function () {
       },
       // Form data
       data: ({url: files[0].link}),
      //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false
   });
```

in browser network console I see that happens folowing request:

```
http://localhost:8081/member/uploadExternalImage?\[object"%"20Object\]&_=1439918533330"
```

It is unexpected result.

Expected result:

```
 http://localhost:8081/member/uploadExternalImage?url=anyValue
```

How to correct my code ?

Comment: Why did you set `processData` to `false`?

Comment: @Stryner your advise helpful

Comment: Using this `'url=' + files[0].link` made any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set processData to true if you want the data object to be converted to query string.